# TSQL Reversing query to display cols as rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following query will gives me

```
Active  Inactive
3       1

SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Inactive
FROM Events
```

I would like to get it like:

```
Status    Count
Active    3
Inactive  1
```

How can I inverse this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for pivoting your resultset, you could use simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CASE Active WHEN 'True' THEN 'Active'
                   WHEN 'False' THEN 'Inactive'
       END AS Status
      ,COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Events
WHERE Active IN ('True', 'False')
GROUP BY CASE Active WHEN 'True' THEN 'Active'
                   WHEN 'False' THEN 'Inactive'
       END;
```

Comment: thank you that works! I'll accept soon as the 8 mins are up